# Dinner party combinatorics (meeting each other once)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-designs

I am hosting a meet-and-greet dinner party but am having troubles with some elementary combinatorics. I got 20 people for a dinner party and they can only sit at tables in groups of 4. What is the minimum number of table arrangements required so that everyone gets to meet each other at least once?

Intuitively, the upper bound is going to be 20 choose 4 = 4845, as these are the total number of ways to choose sub-groups of 4 from a group of 20. However, this number seems too high but I don't know exactly how to work from here.

For a simpler case, if I have 5 people and have tables for 4, it seems I only need 3 different rounds of table arrangements to get my result: (1,2,3,4)5; 1(2,3,4,5); (1)2(3,4,5). Everyone has met everyone now. Clearly 5 choose 4 = 5 > 3. But I'm having troubles finding the exact principle here. The furthest I've gone is that we have 5 choices for the 1st member of a group of 4, 4 choices for the 2nd member, 3 choices for the 3rd, and 2 choices for the 4th. But I am not sure what number to divide this by to get the result we want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand "$(1,2,3,4)5; 1(2,3,4,5); (1)2(3,4,5)$". How are these arrangements with tables for three?

Comment: @joriki Corrected the example (I think?). Yes, I am trying to help someone organize an actual event and want to reduce the number of table transitions required for this networking event.

Comment: Actually, how many tables do you have? This maybe beyond the handshaking problem. So, firstly we set as pairs of four everyinto the table, then a question is, how to swap people between tables, such that everyone greets in least number of swaps

Comment: I guess the issue is that, in the explicit example you gave, the second table you made is somehow based on the first table you made. It's made by kicking some people out of the table, and putting some other in while preserving some. In the original case, it counts both where we kick and put some new in, but also ones where the ones in the table at nth table sitting and n+1th table sitting is totally different. So for instance, in the first table could be 1,2,3,4 and the second could person 20,19,18,17

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Not quite because my problem is simpler in that there isn't the condition that people have to sit next to each other. Just imagine tables as like sets of 4 people chosen from 20 people. What is the minimum number of table arrangements required for everyone to have been part of the same set at least once?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom: That also has the condition that people must sit next to each other. The problem here is the [social golfer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem).

Comment: This is not quite social golfer, which instead tries to *maximize* the number of rounds, while covering each pair at *most* once.  Here, we want to *minimize* the number of rounds while covering each pair at *least* once.

Comment: @RobPratt: That's true. A Steiner system would solve both problems at once, but if no Steiner system exists (as in this case, since the divisibility condition isn't satisfied) the solutions might differ slightly. But in both cases most pairs of people must meet exactly once.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100315/how-many-rounds-would-it-take-to-get-each-pair-on-the-same-team-at-least-once-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s your party schedule in $7$ rounds:

```
14 16  1  0    11  5  9  8    10 12  2  7    19 17 15 13    18  3  6  4    
11  7 17 16    15 12  0  6     1 18  8 10    13  9 14  3     5  4  2 19    
 3 11  0  2    17 14 10  4    18 15  9  7     6  8 19 16    13  5  1 12    
10  9  0 19    13  4 15 16     2 11 18  1    14  7  6  5    12  8  3 17    
 3  7  1 19    11 13 10  6     9 12 16  4     5  0 18 17    14 15  2  8    
 1 17  6  9    12 11 14 19    15  5 10  3     7  8  0  4    18 13  2 16    
16 10  3  5    18 14 19 12     8  7 13  0     2  6  9 17     1 15  4 11
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/joriki/4d2569d89b1bc92de14df4aea9ddc0b0)’s the simulated annealing code I wrote to find it.

Since everyone needs to meet $19$ people and can only meet $3$ new people per round, this is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You must cover $\binom{20}{2}$ pairs, and each round covers $5 \binom{4}{2}$ pairs, so a lower bound is $$\left\lceil\frac{\binom{20}{2}}{5 \binom{4}{2}}\right\rceil = 7$$ rounds.

8 is an upper bound:

```
1
{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8}
{9,10,11,12}
{13,14,15,16}
{17,18,19,20}
2
{1,7,15,20}
{3,6,16,18}
{9,12,14,17}
{4,5,10,11}
{2,8,13,19}
3
{8,9,12,20}
{4,16,17,19}
{3,11,13,15}
{1,5,7,18}
{2,6,10,14}
4
{7,10,15,19}
{3,4,8,14}
{5,6,12,16}
{2,11,17,20}
{1,9,13,18}
5
{10,14,18,20}
{1,6,11,19}
{5,8,15,17}
{3,4,12,13}
{2,7,9,16}
6
{1,12,14,19}
{4,6,9,15}
{3,7,10,17}
{2,5,13,20}
{8,11,16,18}
7
{7,11,12,14}
{1,8,10,16}
{6,13,15,17}
{3,5,9,19}
{2,4,18,20}
8
{3,6,16,20}
{1,8,17,19}
{5,9,11,14}
{2,12,15,18}
{4,7,10,13}
```

Comment: This is really just $\left\lceil\frac{20-1}{4-1}\right\rceil=\left\lceil\frac{19}3\right\rceil=7$; everything else cancels out. Each guest must meet $20-1=19$ people and meets $4-1$ people per round.